# JavaScript tree functionality without framework

Tags: javascript, facebook, tree, fbjs, no-framework

I'd like to display a tree on a Facebook page with JavaScript.  Therefore there can be no dependencies on frameworks such as jQuery or [Ext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_%28JavaScript_library%29) which won't run on Facebook, at least as far as I know when I last worked on that platform (April 2009).  Can anybody recommend a "framework-free" JavaScript/tree library?  I have ported some fairly complex JavaScript to Facebook so I'm sure I'll be able to port just about any existing pure JavaScript library.

Clarification points:

- I am targeting [FBJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#Facebook_Markup_Language)
- I too can (and did) google for JavaScript/tree engines but am seeking recommendations as to which one(s)

Comment: Did you tried to just copy the framework’s source into your page?

Comment: @Gumbo, Facebook uses a restricted, sanitized JS.

Comment: Before you post please consider this: what part of "no framework" do you not understand?  Frankly I am disgusted that I should ask a question specifically seeking to exclude Javascript frameworks, and then the thread devolved into discussion of the very sort of thing I had explicitly asked to exclude.

Comment: Ya, that kind of crap happens around here.  It's jQuery or the highway, don't you know ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this implementation... http://www.destroydrop.com/javascripts/tree/

Comment: Posted a much less simple/direct method, then saw this one and deleted mine. :) This seems like exactly what the OP is looking for!  Bravo.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't describe the requirements for your JS tree, so I would suggest you write one yourself. It's a relatively simple task unless you need more complex functionality.

A simple tree is just a matter of having a bunch of DOM nodes that have other DOM nodes inside them that can be toggled on and off (display block/none)

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the munging in FBJS.  Not sure why it would make jQuery not work, but if someone has some insight, I'd love to hear it.

I do know that you probably can't use jQuery's $ due to conflicts.  But that can be changed from $() to jQuery() easily enough.

I could tell you what treeview I like, but without trying it in Facebook it might fail for the same reasons as jQuery.

Comment: He might be running FBJS instead of JavaScript.

Comment: FaceBook is working on FBJS2, which might be close enough to get jQuery running.

It's not the munging that kills jQuery--it's the missing and altered functionality (lack of innerHTML, etc).

Here's a discussion: http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=27577&p=1

Comment: Another reason why JQuery does not work on FB is that the FBJS/sandbox disallows access to the necessary facets of Javascript and the DOM API needed by JQuery's (dom) "ready" functionality

Answer (score 1):

Even if you work mostly in FBML and FBJS, you can use `<fb:iframe/>` to render raw HTML and JavaScript without the FB munging going on.

What kind of page are you targeting? `<fb:iframe/>` works on canvas pages but not on a user's profile page.

Comment: Well I think I want to target FBJS.  This will start on a canvas page, but eventually may grow into an application, and if I recall, fb/iframe is not applicable for an "app in a tab"

Answer (score 1):

You really should write and test your own to get exactly what you want, and you didn't describe exactly what you want from a tree, but perhaps you could try the free version of [treeview](http://www.treeview.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#nested with great success. The default UI might throw you off (it doesn't look like a tree) but when you consider mobile users this look actually works much better.